# How to find and import default CSS tags from PHP file

Tags: php, css, phpstorm

I have a report generation page, that is PHP based, but I can't use basic CSS classes in it for some reasons. For example, the `i-column-header` class doesn't do anything. I am Using PhpStorm and if I go into a CSS file, I see that it has the classes, and it says "from html".

[image]

I am not sure where the `html` is located, or how to reference it from my PHP file. I am OK with just having a CSS file with all of those default classes hanging around.

Can anyone please tell me where to find the classes, or if there is a resource where they are located. I have tried looking this up, but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Looking at  your screenshot, you must be editing the CSS. For me this means that the `i-column-header` is used in the actual HTML part (e.g. `<div class="i-column-header"...`) and may not have the actual style defined in CSS yet. I suggest you use `Find | Find in Files` (`Ctrl+Shift+F` on Windows/Linux in most Keymaps) to do a project-wide search and see where that class is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the classes requested and they work ok in the PHP files.
**But a word of caution for the future people looking at this Question and Answer**

> Do not use CSS files, as they don't really work well with PHP. When defining your own classes, define them in the PHP file, or an HTML file with a `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is 'intellisense' suggestions created by indexing all the content in the project. There doesn't have to be something in the CSS file.

Comment: I don't have any other css files in the project

Comment: And where do I find the definitions of those classes? I have found a couple of CSS files in my local server settings, but none of them have the `i-column-header` class

Comment: No other files at all? It says it indexed a html file and found these references.

Comment: No, I have no other files that have styles written in them.

Comment: You might want to reference class ids from html files. Why wouldn't the IDE search html for references to css classes? <div class="i-column-header">?

Comment: I tried the solution from PythonSnek and it worked. I think the IDE does search html. But it even with the Professional version it doesn't search for them in PHP files unless you define them, which is what threw me off.